# What does (_) mean when calling a function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I’ve seen the notation used elsewhere but, just as an example, I recently read about replacing

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (BuildContext context) => MyCounter()
```

with

```
 ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (_) => MyCounter()
```

What does the latter notation mean? Is the BuildContext parameter optional and the caller chosen to not supply it?

Comment: It creates an anonymous function with one argument that is not used anywhere in its body.

Comment: I’m a newbie, but why would a function include an argument that isn’t used? It sounds superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing a parameter with `_` simply means **just ignore it**.

Many functions provide parameters that are likely needed for certain operations in most cases, yet there are still some cases where you don't need it (like your case), in which it is safe to ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

In dart, underscore means `private`, when used into anonymous function, means something that are not necessary using in that context, but could be any name, it's just a common notation, likely that parameter is "private" and you aren't using it (but nothing stops you to use with `_` name, like `_.getHashCode()`)

The use depends on context, for example `BuildContext context`, sometimes, you will receive it, but not always you'll use it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a variable named `_` typically because you plan to not use it and throw it away. For example, you can use the name `x` or `foo` instead. The difference between `(_)` and `()` is simple in that one function takes an argument and the other doesn't.